# "Intersecting branches" using Git

Tags: git

The title is not quite correct, I just I haven't come up with a better title for this question.

We're currently working on a development project, and as usually each developer creates its own branch for each his task. After implementing the task the code review begins. When the code review is finished the branch is merged into a development branch.

The problem is that almost all our tasks require writing a code (.cpp and .h files) that is common. I mean that upon finishing his task each developer has some files that are conceptually the same as another developer's files - they must be in the same directory and their purpose and functionality is the same. Currently this "common" part of sources is updated and modified during development by each developer - each developer currently writes its own version of a this common code. And it will obviously create merge conflicts later when merging the task into the development branch.

As a possible solution we could first write all the common code and only then start implementing the tasks. But this approach would require us to delay the tasks until all common code is written, which is not acceptable.

We can't do many commits into the development branch because merging with a development branch requires a long code review procedure.

So we're thinking of an optimal way to organize this kind of development using Git. Could you please advise us a good approach?

Comment: The optimum thing to do here is to not have two or more feature branches which are modifying the same regions of your codebase.  Fix your Git workflow, and this problem should largely go away.

Comment: Thank you, but how should we fix the workflow?

Comment: You can't separate the files on which people are working on? With imports?

Comment: Do you know, if correctly written common code by one developer will always work for each developer?

Comment: @NewEyes No, this "common" part of sources is updated and modified during development by each developer untlil all the tasks are finished

Comment: One of the ways can be, keep a branch for common code. Make devs working on their individual branches, merge their branch with common code branch at the end of each day. Every dev branch will have same commit for common code and it may possibly reduce conflicts.

Comment: @HRK44 These common files are separate ones. They are either included or just required to be in certain place for compilation

Comment: And you can't just let one guy write the common part for everyone?

Comment: @NewEyes One guy who maintains a branch that is being not merged with the development branch. But we take the code from this branch?

Comment: Maybe you can separate the "common part" into a separate dependency that is maintained by same developers but has more relaxed review policy? (Having to switch project seems less troublesome to me than juggling branches)